# Pass a function to be applied as function argument in dbplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

Let's say I want to create a function which can mutate a column using any function which is passed by the user. I need to know how to quote and unquote that function *before* it hits the dbplyr parser. Let's take a look at an example, say I have a function like this:

```r
testFun <- function(data, fun, colName, colOut = "myAwesomeColumn") {
  dplyr::mutate(.data = data, !!colOut := fun(.data[[colName]]))
}

sc <- sparklyr::spark_connection(master = "local")
mtcars_spark <- dplyr::copy_to(sc, mtcars, "mtcars")
testFun(mtcars_spark, mean, "mpg")
```

So in the above example, I want to apply the `mean()` function to the `"mpg"` column and store it in a new column called `"myAwesomeColumn"`.

When working with Spark, and specifically sparklyr, there will be an attempt by dbplyr to convert this code to SQL and send it to Spark. My understanding is that dbplyr applies the following rules:

1. If it can find a Spark SQL equivalent, it will use that (e.g. `mean()` -> `AVG`)
2. Otherwise it will pass the function as-is to look for Scala extensions or UDFs

The second option is what happens here since it cannot find the function `fun` and it therefore returns a Spark error

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'fun'.
This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function
registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 85
...
```

So we need another approach. The problem is getting rlang to convert `fun` to `mean` before this is interpreted by dbplyr. I know I can do this if I pass the function name as a string and use `rlang::parse_expr()`, for example:

```r
testFun <- function(data, fun, colName, colOut = "myAwesomeColumn") {
  dplyr::mutate(data, !!colOut := rlang::parse_expr(paste0(fun, "(", colName, ")"))
}
testFun(mtcars_spark, "mean", "mpg")
# # Source: spark<?> [?? x 12]
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb myAwesomeColumn
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4            20.1
#  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4            20.1
# # ... with more rows
```

Comment: What problem should the solution solve? Do you want to avoid parsing a string with `rlang::parse_expr`?  Should the input be a bare name (e.g. `mean`) instead of a string (`“mean”`)?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I want to pass `mean` instead of `"mean"`.

Comment: I do not have Spark and sparklyr, so I cannot test it. I would try `rlang::call2` and unquoting with `!!` since the bang bang operator evaluates its objects earlier. But I have no idea if this will work. `testFun <- function(data, fun, colName, colOut = "myAwesomeColumn") {
  .fun <- enquo(fun)
  dplyr::mutate(.data = data, !!colOut := eval(call2(!! .fun, .data[[colName]])))
}`

Comment: This almost worked, I made a slight tweak and now it _does_ work. I'll post my answer, thanks.

Comment: Good to see that I was barking up the right tree using {rlang}’s `call2` and the double quoting and unquoting of `fun`. I am kinda surprised that we do not need to `eval` the output of `call2`. Still wondering where this happens. And I am also surprised that this works on  a `tbl_spark` but not on a `data.frame` (here I get an error).

Comment: Indeed, the process for a `data.frame` is different because you do not need to do any quoting and unquoting of `fun`, it just works out of the box. It all comes down to how the dbplyr interpreter works and at what point the `!!` happens (before the R code executes). Out of curiosity I also tried `base::as.call()` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get this to work, we must quote and unquote the `fun` argument. We also build the expression that we actually want to pass into our call to `mutate()`. See below for the solution.

```r
testFun <- function(data, fun, colAmount, colOut = "output") { 
  fun <- rlang::enquo(fun) 
  dplyr::mutate(.data = data, !!colOut := rlang::call2(.fn = !!fun, rlang::sym(colAmount))) 
} 
     
testFun(mtcars_spark, mean, "mpg")                                                                                                                                 
# # Source: spark<?> [?? x 12]
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb output
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4   20.1
#  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4   20.1
# # ... with more rows
```

Note that this is much simpler if you are using `data.frame`s rather than `tbl_spark`s.